# How to realize the API of custom event object?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, dom-events

How to realize the API of custom event object, and the function showing in note (Test 1).
That API of Event object needed be reused by extend (Test 2).

```
Event.on('test',function(result){
    console.log(result);
})
Event.on('test',function(){
    console.log('test');
})
Event.emit('test','hello world');//output 'test'和'hello world'
//test2
var person1 = {};
var person2 = {};
Object.assign(person1,Event);
Object.assign(person2,Event);
person1.on('call1',function(){
    console.log('person1');
});
person2.on('call2',function(){
    console.log('person2');
});
person1.emit('call1'); //output 'person1'
person1.emit('call1'); //not output
person1.emit('call1'); //not output
person1.emit('call1'); //output 'person2'

var Event= {
    //through on api watch event evenName
    //if event eventName was triggered，execute callback function
    on:function(eventName,callback){
        //your code
    },
    //trigger event eventName
    emit:function(eventName){
        //your code
    }
}
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. This looks a lot like "please fill in the gaps". Can you show us what you have tried and where your problem is?

Comment: Assuming this is on node, why don't you use the builtin [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html)?

Answer (score -1):

```
var Event = {
    on: function(eventName, callback){
      //todo
      if(!this[eventName])
      this[eventName] = [];
      this[eventName].push(callback);
   },
   emit: function(eventName){
   //todo
    if(this[eventName])
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(this[eventName], function(func){
      func.call(this);
    });
  }
}

Event.on("one", function(){
  console.log("go");
})
Event.on("one", function(){
  console.log("gogo");
})

Event.emit("one");

var person1 = Object.assign({}, Event);
var person2 = Object.assign({}, Event);
person1.on("666", function(){
  console.log("person1 666");
})
person2.on("777", function(){
  console.log("person2 777");
})

person1.emit("666");
person1.emit("777");
person2.emit("777");
person2.emit("666");
```